# Becoming a Jungler in ranked, Any tips on how i can become more consistent?

Tags: league-of-legends

As of right now, I'm around 1350 ELO and I am winning a lot more than I had before as jungling seems to fit my playstyle and I enjoy it more than most roles in the game.

Yet, I feel like I could always be doing more than just warding for my team, counter-jungling when necessary, and ganking for my lanes to help keep them ahead.

Anyone got any extra tips or anything I could pick up to help sharpen my skills and rise that ladder that everyone desperately wants to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are doing everything right. Make sure to keep buff, dragon, and baron timers. If you can get your whole team to help try and steal all the enemy buffs instead of just taking their wraiths occasionally.

Comment: thanks :D i just wanted clarification/any extra help to make sure im doing everything i can be doing to help benefit myself and my team.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have found helpful with improving my game is by watching streams of other players.  Try going to The stream list on LeagueofLegends.com and watch some high elo players play.  I suggest TheOddOne if you wanna learn how to jungle well.

Answer (score 0):

Think about who you're jungling and how it complements laners. Don't just gank mindlessly. Only gank if you think you have a reasonable chance of killing/forcing them to waste summoners and base.

Set up more sophisticated ganks by going through lane and bushes. Surprise ganks are very effective barring bush wards. Consider getting an oracles early to completely shut down lanes.